# Remote server is ahead after pushing from local

Tags: git, github

I asked this yesterday but didn't ask my question right so no one was able to help. So I'll try again.

**I add a repo**

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:user/test.git
git add .
git commit -m "initial"
git push origin master
```

**I ssh into my web server and git clone**

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/test.git
cd test
```

**I set up my hook in server, add a git checkout then give permission to file**

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
vim .git/hooks/post-recieve
GIT_WORK_TREE=../ git checkout -f
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-recieve
```

**I add my ssh into server authorized keys.**

**I then add my remote server from local**

```
git remote add test user@server.com:test
```

**On git remote -v I get**

```
test    user@server.com:test (fetch)
test    user@server.com:test (push)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:user/test.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:user/test.git (push)
```

**I then add a file**

```
touch test.php
git add test.php
git commit -m "test page"
git push origin master
```

**I then push to server**

```
git push test master
```

**In server when ls -l I only get one file index.php
When I do git status I get**

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    test.php
#
```

I then have to run git stash to get all files.

So the head is at the correct position. It's retrived the test.php file but then deleted it?

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely stupid, wasted a full day yesterday trying to solve this and it was a stupid typo.

```
vim .git/hooks/post-recieve
```

Spelt receive wrong

```
vim .git/hooks/post-receive
```

I'm just going to go kill my self.